# Standalone Java App dies after a few days

Tags: java, linux, sockets, log4j, rmi

We have a Java App that connects via RMI to another Java app.
There are multiple instances of this app running at the same time, and after a few days an instance just stops processing... the CPU is in 0 and I have an extra thread listening to an specific port that helps to shutdown the App.

I can connect to the specific port but the app doesn't do anything.

We're using Log4j to keep a log and nothing is written, so there aren't any exceptions thrown.

We also use c3p0 for the DB connections.

Anyone have ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: "no exceptions thrown"? Are you sure you have checked the stdout (standard output) and stderr (standard error) too? Or only the log file? Check where does the output go to...

Comment: "any ideas"? Yes ... you have a bug. This is pretty unanswerable here in this form. You'll need to start debugging where your process is hanging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest starting with a thread dump of the affected application. 
You need to see what is going on on a thread by thread basis. It could be that you have a long running thread, or other process which is blocking other work from being done.

Since you are running linux, you can get your thread dump with the following command

```
kill -3 <pid>
```

If you need help reading the output, please post it in your original question.

If nothing is shown from the thread dump, other alternatives can be looked at.

Comment: 1+ For going with the basics lol. I admit that I tend  to jump the gun with JMetter + JConsole. Anyway, as a second step, JConsole can give you very useful information with very little configuration (the tool is also very intuitive).

Answer (score 0):

Hum... I would suggest using [JMetter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) to stress the Application and take note of anything weird that might be happening (such as Memory Leaks, Deadlocks and such). Also review the code for any Exceptions that might interrupt the program (or System.exit() calls). Finally, if other people have access to the computer, makes sense to check if the process wasn't killed manually somehow.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot the most import part. For the actual monitoring you can go with [JConsole](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) which can be used remotely. Both are really good (and free) tools.